# Calculate SHA1 or MD5 hash in iReport

Tags: java, md5, sha1, ireport

How would one calculate an SHA1 or MD5 hash within iReport at report execution?  I need to compare a pre-calculated hash against a database driven field (string).

Using iReport 2.0.5 (Old) and Report Engine is embedded into a commercial application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used iReport and Jasper Reports some years ago and I don't remember the details, but I remember that you could put in some way Java code to be evaluated. Using that feature you could calculate the MD5 in few lines:

```
String encryptionAlgorithm = "MD5";
String valueToEncrypt = "StackOverflow";
MessageDigest msgDgst = MessageDigest.getInstance(encryptionAlgorithm);
msgDgst.update(valueToEncrypt.getBytes(), 0, valueToEncrypt.length());
String md5 = new BigInteger(1, msgDgst.digest()).toString(16) ;
System.out.println(md5);
```

Need to import java.math.BigInteger, java.security.MessageDigest and java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

To calculate SHA1 hash is almost the same:

```
String encryptionAlgorithm = "SHA-1";
String valueToEncrypt = "StackOverflow";
MessageDigest msgDgst = MessageDigest.getInstance(encryptionAlgorithm);
byte[] sha1hash = new byte[40];
msgDgst.update(valueToEncrypt.getBytes(), 0, valueToEncrypt.length());
sha1hash = md.digest();
```

Check this blog post about the creation of variables that can be evaluated at report run time  http://www.eakes.org/77/java-injection-in-jasper-reports/

Comment: Thanks!  I will definitely check this out.

Comment: Well.  I was able to get the imports for the message digest & exception classes, and calculate the hashes. 

Here is the result variable. http://pastebin.com/f5dabd0a9

What is weird is in the console the expression is run twice. Thus prints twice.  

My next goal is to get this java code to return boolean to the variable.  Not sure how to do that yet.