# How to generate hash(SHA1) using beanshell in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, sha1, cryptojs, beanshell

How do I want to generate a hash using beanshell(SHA1) in JMeter to sign up to a application?

I'm not able to get a substantial answer yet from net

Comment: There is some script for SHA1 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589996/calculate-sha1-or-md5-hash-in-ireport Try it, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating a hash is pretty easy, just use [DigestUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) class from Apache [Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) library (it's a part of JMeter so you won't need to install anything external)

Something like:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

String foo = "bar";
String sha1Hex = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(foo);
```

Usually SHA1 is being required for signing requests to OAuth-protected applications, if it is your case, I believe [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new JMeter function `__digest`, currently in [nightly builds](https://builds.apache.org/job/JMeter-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/dist/) which can be used to encode strings

[image]

In your case to save in sha1Value variable the result of myVar variable use the following:

```
${__digest(SHA-1,${myVar},,,sha1Value)}
```

4th parameter is uppercase, so you can send true to automatically uppercase it.